# React Native - cache DOM?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I have a component in React Native that needs to render pretty big array. That array is an in memory object and it takes about one second to render whole view.

So it's not a big deal when the app is showing up but there are couple of other screens that user can navigate to and when he navigates back it takes again around one second to render that view. And that's pretty annoying.

Is there any way I could render a component once and keep it in some cache or something? So that when user navigates out and get's back to this view it will be shown immidiately?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i typed in react native cache in google and found a few things that are promising. start there.

Comment: dude, seriously? react-native-cache is totally about different thing than I ask. I don't want to cache images as well. Is there anything else that you googled out?

Comment: dude. try this. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-simple-store

Comment: I'm not trying to cache an object. That's easy. I'm trying to cache a component so it won't rerender itself after navigating back to it. That's a totally different story.

Comment: do the objects in the array change? and how big is big? you can take your code into android studio and use native java code possibly.

Comment: No, they're static. Array is ~250 elements long but each of them is quite long text so the render method takes around a second everytime.
I also have a method that's parsing this array into bunch of elements and I tried to do this part asynchrously but that doesn't help. It's the render itself that takes long.
I know that FlatList is optimized for long list but there's pretty specific scenario in my project that just forces me to render all the stuff at once.

Comment: do you know how to bring the code into android studio and combine it? because its possible you can create a String array in xml and call on them. Not sure if its going to be quicker than 1second, but its possible itll work. or even use sqlite once the application loads you dump it into sqlite on the device. OR, dump it into storage on the device.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest rendering in chunks of size `n`(whatever gives you best-perceived performance) instead of rendering the entire 250 item list.

Did some more digging on caching react views and found this https://github.com/zhaoyao91/react-view-cache. Haven't tried it myself but maybe it helps.

Comment: Overall idea of that component is pretty clever so I might give it a try. But it will only work with react, not react native. But it might be fairly easy to tweak it a little bit so thanks for the idea.